# Optimising a sentence search across multiple documents

Tags: php, search

I am having issues optimising a search I created in PHP, this search is for one time use, so flexibility is not that important.

I have a array of sentences, like:

```
$arr = [
   'potato',
   'hi my name is Ivan'
    ..
];
```

The array contains about 1k sentences.

And I have a hard disk with 200 GB of files.

I need to search all of the files and see if any of these sentences are inside the files, and if so, to print out the path, a checksum, etc in a specific format.

The issue I am facing is search time, when doing something like this, which seems inefficient:

```
$objections = [];
foreach ($files as $file) {

    if (!in_array($file->getExtension(), $allowedExt))
        continue;

    $txt = file_get_contents($file);

    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (stripos($txt, $word) !== false ||
            stripos($file->getFilename(), $word) !== false
            ) {
            $file->c_md5 = getCMD5($file);
            $objections[] = $file;
        }
    }
}
```

The search it self is taking ages 1h+, and I am on a new MacBook with the latest i7. With PHP memory etc maxed.

It is not relevant which word is matched in the array of words, so I was wondering if there is some more clever way to perform the search instead of looping the words inside the file loop. Would a very long REGEX string with OR's be faster?

Or is there some third way which is a lot fast.

Comment: I don't know if a big regex would be faster, but if you have an idea on how to do one (which you seem to), just try it and benchmark. With that amount of data it will probably be very slow regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely answer is an regex. You should probably split it into three stages:

1. Convert your list of sentences into one big regex or a list of regexes to be run in a loop. You can convert spaces to whitespaces `\s` and make the search un-greedy `/regex/U`.
2. Iterate over files and remove line endings replacing it with spaces. Just in case an sentence is spread across multiple lines.
3. Use `preg_match` to find out if the sentence is in the file. You can do it in the loop if you decide for multiple regexes.

Comment: I think that if you go with regex, you should have one big regex, otherwise you're basically just implemented a slower way of doing what the original code already does. Regex is not efficient for simple string comparisons. (but it gets more efficient if you don't need to loop through every sentence on every file).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I agree, one big regex should be better.

Answer (score 0):

A Regex will save you little or nothing.

You can break out of the loop on a hit.

```
Foreach{
    If(hit){
        Break;
    }
}
```

Which would save searching for the rest. So if you hit on the second iteration you'll no longer have to do another 998 iterations of that document.

The problem you are always going to have is the opening of a document, that without a doubt is where most of your performance will be lost.

If this is an operation you need to perform more than once, it's probably worth considering indexing all of your files into a database designed for full text search ElasticSearch for example. Within your database you could then simply retain a reference to the physical file for whatever the next operation is. 
The initial loading and indexing of all these files will admittedly take some big resources and time. However once complete your searches will be **really** fast.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to add this, matches are rare tho, but yeah, should def save some time

Comment: Then I'd seriously look into implementing a database such as ElasticSearch as mentioned. You're already loading all the file contents, throwing it intiba database would be trivial, and then the search will require a couple of functions. The documentation for ElasticSearch is great.

Comment: Even full text search on MySQL might be quicker.

Comment: More than likely, yes. However if you're going to the trouble of populating a database with this amount of data, the logical option would be to use a database designed for this kind of operation, no relational data and very few writes. Though MySQL would probably be the easier to setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec`

create a test.php file and try this code

```
  <?php
    exec('grep '.escapeshellarg('end').' '."./test.php",$result);              
    print_r($result);
    /* serach for some sentences
     * keep seraching
     * end of comment */
  ?>
```

Ofcourse you will have to test its performance first then customize it to your needs